# Take different elements of list in Clipboard

Tags: applescript

I define the clipboard as a list of items,

```
set clipData to {23, 21, 44, 76}
set the clipboard to clipData
```

In the Applescript application, I'd now like to past the different elements of the clipboard separately. I'm currently using

```
tell application "System Events"
   keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
```

however, I'd like to only paste individuel elements of the list in the clipboard.

Any idea about how to make this work with Applescript?

Thanks!

Comment: Get the whole content and then select the value you need. Not sure how safe it is to use the clipboard for things like that though, it can be overwritten anytime.

Comment: How would you filter for the value one needs, after getting the whole content? Thanks!

Comment: I'm no AppleScript expert but probably the same way as with any normal variable set to `{23, 21, 44, 76}`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the list using `repeat with ... end repeat`
2. Save each element to the clipboard `as text` if you want it to be pasted as text
3. Afterwards, save the whole list to the clipboard

```
set clipData to {23, 21, 44, 76}

repeat with element in clipData
    set the clipboard to element as text
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
end repeat

set the clipboard to clipData
```

More info:

- [`repeat with` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128481)
- [`as` (coercion) documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_operators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH5g-SW5)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: will try this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
set ClipData to {23, 21, 44, 76}

set the clipboard to convertListToString(ClipData, linefeed)

on convertListToString(theList, theDelimiter)
    
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter,
    set theString to theList as string,
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "",
    return theString;
end convertListToString
```

Comment: Please don’t post a code-only answer, explain what the it does and how it solves the problem stated in the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).